# How to connect to mongodb whern I have ip, username and password

Tags: mongodb

I have ip address of mongodb, user name and password. How to access to db and list data? I know mysql but this is Spain village to me. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Not enough information to help you. But you could have a look over here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect using:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

But that would depend on what driver you are using, please, refer to MongoDB Docs on [Connections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use command line, do this:

`path_to_your_local_mongo_installation/bin/mongo ip_address -u username -p` replacing `ip_address` with the IP address you have, and `username` is the username.

Then, to see the list of databases use:

`show dbs`

To pick a database, use:

`use dbname` assuming dbname is the name of the database

To show collections within that database, use:

`show collections`